# Dirichlet series as rational zeta expressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $D(f,s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^s}$, otherwise known as a Dirichlet series. When $f$ is a multiplicative, number theoretic function, $D(f,s)$ tends to be expressed as a rational product of zeta functions. For example, $D(\mu,n) = \zeta^{-1}(s)$, $D(\sigma,n)=\zeta(s)\zeta(s-1)$, $D(\phi,n) = \zeta(s-1)/\zeta(s)$, and [many, many more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Examples).

Question 1: Is it possible to deduce for which family of $f$, $D(f,s) = \frac{\prod_{a_i}\zeta(s-a_i)}{\prod_{b_i}\zeta(s-b_i)}$?

Question 2: Conversely, given an arbitrary such rational product of zeta functions, does it always correspond to some multiplicitive number-theroteic function? If yes, have any new "interesting" such functions been discovered by such methods?

As I understand, it the answer these questions should likely follow from [Perron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula), but I'm not seeing an obvious way of proceeding. In fact, the questions seem to reduce to basic generating function theory, along with the inclusion-exclusion principle, as many of the above known number-theoretic identities can be derived from it as such.

Comment: Couldn't Dirichlet convolution provide a good framework to answer your question ? I expect the existence of some automorphism group of the considered ring of arithmetic functions preserving the set of rational zeta expressions.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: Right, the product in the numerator can definitely be interpreted as convolutions of dirichlet series. The one in the denominator is stranger. To your point, I'd love to see a reference for the area that studies these rational expressions.

Comment: I'm not talking about convolution of Dirichlet series but about Dirichlet convolution of arithmetic functions. See for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution

Comment: Every product/quotient of translates of the Riemann zeta function can be expressed as a Euler product, and the Euler factor is a rational function in $X=p^{-s} $. Then the values $f (p^n) $ simply corresponds to the coefficients of the Taylor expansion of this rational function at $X=0$.

Comment: You want just zetas, no L-functions? What is the motivation for this problem?